# KoGrid not working in Durandal JS framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, durandal

How can i bind a koGrid in durandal JS view page.The code given below not working.

view(html)

```
  <div id="functiontable" class="form-actions">
                        <div style="height: 200px" data-bind="koGrid: {
                                 data: items, columnDefs: [{ field: 'id', width: 140 },
                                    { field: 'name', width: 100 },
                                    { field: 'price', width: 150 }
                                ],
                            autogenerateColumns: false,
                            isMultiSelect: false,
                             enableSorting: true
                        }"></div>

                    </div>
```

viewmodel(js)

```
define([ 'repositories/customerRepository', 'plugins/router', 'plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (customerRepository, router, http, app, ko) {
var items = ko.observableArray([
 { id: 1, name: "abc", price: "asds" },
{id:1,name:"abc",price:"asds"},
]);
return {
    router: router,
    items:items, 
    activate: function () {


    },
    attached: function (view) {

    },



};});
```

If I inspect the element from browser the grid loads its value.I don't know how to clear the issue.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

Items needs to actually be returned in order to be used by your view, so:

```
items: ko.observableArray([
       { id: 1, name: "abc", price: "asds" },
       {id:1,name:"abc",price:"asds"}
]),
activate: function () {

}
```

**Tip**
When doing this stuff, use a client-side debugger such as the Chrome web tools (F12 in Chrome) - that'll highlight that "items" cannot be found.